# Function Composition (Continuation)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, function-and-relation-composition

Continuing from the answer of this thread [(Link)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1150645/question-about-function-composition)

"As you notice, for this to work everywhere in the desired domain, **we need the domain of $f$ to be (or at least contain) the range of $g$**. Thus, the proper definition would have $g:A\rightarrow B$ and $f:B\rightarrow C$ with $f\circ g:A\rightarrow C$."

My question is :

1) In the case above, if we define

$A=\{1, 2\}$

$B=\{r, s, t\}$

$D=\{r, s, u\}$

$C=\{x, y\}$

and

$g:A\rightarrow B$

$f:D\rightarrow C$

image  of $g$ $=\{r, s\}$

Will the composition $f\circ g$ still be valid or will it be undefined    in this case?

Comment: The domain of $f$ contains the image of $g$, so yes the composition makes sense.

Comment: So you are saying that in $f\circ g$ the domain of $f$ does not have to be the same as the codomain of $g$?

Comment: It is sufficient that $\text{im }g \subseteq \text{dom}f$. They don't have to be equal.

Comment: "It is sufficient that $im g$ is a subset of $dom f$" Can you give me a recommendation or textbook that states as so?

Comment: I'm asking for a  textbook reference because your statement is in contradiction with the second answer here : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1137476/for-a-composition-to-be-defined-domf-circ-g-subseteq-dom-f-im-f-circ-g-subse?rq=1